# How can I make different shapes of a canvas draggable and particular area of it droppable in the same canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, drag-and-drop

I want to create a Canvas in which there will be two areas (Left and right), Left panel will contain some shapes which will be draggable(static as well) and on the right side I would be able to drop them, but I am facing following problem,

1. I am not able to make the shapes which i draw on the left side, draggable, because there is no id associated with them.
2. I do not know how to make some particular area droppable.

Here is code to visualize what I am trying to achieve-

```
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(250,0);
ctx.lineTo(250,600);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(50,50,160,25);
ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
ctx.font = "15px";
ctx.strokeText("Draggable Elements here",57,67);

ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(500,50,130,25);
ctx.font = "15px";
ctx.strokeText("Droppable area Here",510,67);    
</script>

</body>
```

Here is the JS fiddle for the same - 
http://jsfiddle.net/akki166786/4tfyy4o5/

so if anybody can shed some light on how can I achieve this, it will be a great help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In canvas all is pixels blended together, no objects. You need to manually implement the lower logic to handle objects. See if one of the many libraries out there can help (kineticjs,fabricjs, ..).

Comment: Thanks, for the input @K3N , sure i will look in to these libraries and will get back to you,if i will have any doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Drag and drop in specifik area**

**UPDATE:** Copy of box remains at original position while it's being moved.

First you need to be able to detect your rectangles. You do this by making then into objects in your code:

```
function box(x,y,w,h,rgb) {
    this.x = x,
    this.y = y;
    this.xS = x; //saving x
    this.yS = y; //saving y
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.rgb = rgb;

    //to determine if the box is being draged
    this.draging = false;
}
```

No you need to add an event listener to determine if someone is clicking, you also need to determine if the person clicked in one of your boxes.

```
c.addEventListener("mousedown",down);
c.addEventListener("mousemove",move);
c.addEventListener("mouseup",up);
```

So events have been made to detect when the mouse button is pressed down, released back up and if the mouse moves within the canvas. To these events we have functions, down(), move() and up(), ready to be executed.

All functions will be visible in the example below.

When we're happily draging our boxes and releasing our mouse button, we need to check if the box was dropped in the dropable area. We do this in the up()-function. If the drop was OK, the box can stay, otherwise we send it back to where it came from.

**Working example**

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

c.width = 600;
c.height = 300;

//My mouse coordinates
var x,y;
c.addEventListener("mousedown",down);
c.addEventListener("mousemove",move);
c.addEventListener("mouseup",up);

//I'll save my boxes in this array
var myBoxes = new Array();

//This function describes what a box is.
//Each created box gets its own values
function box(x,y,w,h,rgb) {
    this.x = x,
    this.y = y;
    this.xS = x; //saving x
    this.yS = y; //saving y
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.rgb = rgb;
    
    //to determine if the box is being draged
    this.draging = false;
}

//Let's make some boxes!!
myBoxes[0] = new box(10,10,50,100,"green");
myBoxes[1] = new box(80,50,100,75,"blue");
myBoxes[2] = new box(40,150,20,70,"yellow");


//here we draw everything
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
    //Dropable area
    ctx.fillStyle="red";
    ctx.fillRect(c.width/2,0,c.width,c.height);
    
    //Boxes!
    for (var i = 0; i<myBoxes.length; i++) {
        var b = myBoxes[i];

        //NEW CODE FOR UPDATE
        if (b.draging) { //box on the move
            //Also draw it on the original spot
            ctx.fillStyle="grey"; //I chose a different color to make it appear more as a shadow of the box that's being moved.
            ctx.fillRect(b.xS,b.yS,b.w,b.h);
            ctx.strokeRect(b.xS,b.yS,b.w,b.h);
        }
        //End of new code for update

        ctx.fillStyle=b.rgb;
        ctx.fillRect(b.x,b.y,b.w,b.h);
        ctx.strokeRect(b.x,b.y,b.w,b.h);
    }
    
    //Let's keep re-drawing this
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}


function down(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    x = event.pageX - c.offsetLeft,
    y = event.pageY - c.offsetTop;
    
    for (var i = 0; i<myBoxes.length; i++) {
        var b = myBoxes[i];
        if (x>b.x && x<b.x+b.w && y>b.y && y<b.y+b.h) {
            b.draging = true;
        }
    }
}

function move(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    x = event.pageX - c.offsetLeft,
    y = event.pageY - c.offsetTop;
    
    for (var i = 0; i<myBoxes.length; i++) {
        var b = myBoxes[i];
        if (b.draging) {
            b.x = x;
            b.y = y;
        }
    }
}
function up(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    x = event.pageX - c.offsetLeft,
    y = event.pageY - c.offsetTop;
    
    for (var i = 0; i<myBoxes.length; i++) {
        var b = myBoxes[i];
        if (b.draging) {
            //Let's see if the rectangle is inside the dropable area
            if (b.x>c.width/2) {
                //Yes is it!
                b.x = x;
                b.y = y;
                b.draging = false;
            }
            else {
                //No it's not, sending it back to its ordiginal spot   
                b.x = b.xS;
                b.y = b.yS;
                b.draging = false;                
            }

        }
    }
}


draw();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was a great help, just one more thing that when I am dragging the boxes a copy of it should move it with the mouse(as it happening) but the original box should also be in its place, any Idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: See updated answer, added a check to se if the box is being moved. If so, also draw the box in its original position. I chose to make it grey so that it appears kind of like a shadow but that's ofc optional.

Comment: I wanted the original box to be remain at its place even after dropping the box on the other side, but anyways , it was great help by you. Thanks a lot to you.

Comment: @Novice Good job! Depending on what you want to happen on the cnavas, you'll need to adjust the code. If you want the box to be visible on two places at once, you'll need 2 sets of coordinates (which the example above has). If you want to have it visible on 3 locations (original, moving and last good spot in dropable area), you'll need 3 sets of coordinates for each object. Keep on experimenting and if you run into problem, open a new question =)

Answer (score 0):

You're using just one canvas, maybe it would be better if you use two separate canvas, one for each element you want to handle on page. so you'll have one element ID for each one. 
plus. if your drawing is simple, consider using a div for it instead a canvas

Comment: The target which I am having can't be achieved with divs, later on the shapes on the left panel will be of lego shapes which are very difficult to show as/on divs. but about two canvas i can think of buying your argument .

Comment: for every lego piece, you add one canvas, and you can encapsulate a function that draw the piece to canvas, you can pass color and number of rows/cols of the piece it will be very nice! please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Once drawn to the canvas, shapes(or lines, images, everything) are no longer accessible.

What you will need to do is store each shape in an object in your code. For example:

```
var rectangle = {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    x: 50,
    y: 50
}
```

Then when you drag `rectangle`, you will need to update it's `x` and `y` properties on mouseup (or while it's being dragged if you want a drag preview).